# How to update mulitple series in Highcharts simultaneously

Tags: json, dynamic, highcharts, series

I'm using Highcharts to graph multiple series on a single chart. The series data is read from a file containing the data in JSON format. The file will get updated with new data every few seconds and I've a function to re-read the file.
Here's the data in the file:

```
[{"name": "series1", "data": [[1,109],[2,313],[3,192]]},{"name": "series2", "data": [[1,111],[2,112],[3,777]]}]
```

The code I've got is:

```
//Read JSON data from a file
$(function () {

    function getSeriesData(file) {
        var data = null;
        $.ajax({
        async: false,
            cache: false,
        url: file,
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(datasets){
                data = datasets;
            },
            error: function(error,text,http){
                alert("Error retrieving " + url + ".");
            }
        });  

        return data;
    }

    var graphData = getSeriesData("seriesData.json");

    var graphOptions = {
            chart: {
             type: 'line',
             renderTo: "container",
         },
         series: graphData
    };


    var graph = new Highcharts.Chart(graphOptions);

    var updateInterval = 1000 * 5;  // 5 seconds

    function update() {
        //Need to refresh series data here.
                    //Something like:
            graph.series = getSeriesData("series.json");
            graph.redraw();
            setTimeout(update, updateInterval);
    }

    update();});
```

Looking at the documentation there doesn't seem to be a way to set all the series data again at the same time using my getSeriesData function to reread the file. Most of the examples here and elsewhere have ways to set the data for individual series by going through the series[] array. But thats not what I'm looking for. Maybe I'll have to redo the code to do it that way but thought I'd check here first in the hope that there's an easier way! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a way to do all series with one call. I can see two options.

If the number of series is fixed, you can iterate over them calling series.setData with the redraw option set to false, and then call redraw().

If the number of series may change, you will have to iterate over the chart.series calling remove, and then iterate over your series array calling chart.addSeries.

Comment: Thanks Steve. The number of series could change so the second option is what I'll probably have to go with. Pity it doesn't seem to be possible to refresh all in one call.

Comment: When you get JSON, you can get length of series objects, and then you will have numer of iteration.